# HC-06 bluetooth module

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I need help with the blinking LED of my HC-06 Bluetooth module.

I just want to know what it means when it starts blinking, when it's always on and when it's not on at all and how do I know if it's connected or paired by the LED.

My second question is that I'm developing an Android app that sends data to an Arduino UNO board via this Bluetooth module, but every time I try to send my data, the app crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blinking LED means that it's waiting to be connected. When it stops blinking, the connection is established.

Check this great tutorial [here](http://solderer.tv/data-transfer-between-android-and-arduino-via-bluetooth/).

Comment: thank you! I've tried that tutorial before but it always gave me this error 'check that the UUID exists on server'. Do you know why I'm getting that error?

Comment: Also, do you know if the HC-06 receives AND sends data? I thought it only received data but I'm still unable to try to even successfully send data to it and I'm running out of time and hope...

Comment: The module I have DOES send AND receive. It's a Chinese module I got on eBay for very cheap. But it seems very good. The **second** example in the link I posted is very promising, while the first one doesn't seem to work well. Also, you can try using BlueTerm to send and receive data. I also got those errors with the FIRST example.

Comment: I'm going to try that example now but I'm having a problem with the diagram. The LED wiring is not clear to me, is he wiring it with the module? Do you happen to have a better, more clear diagram? My module only has 4 pins so it is not an option for me, as far as I know, to connect the LED directly with the module as shown (I think) in that diagram.. excuse my ignorance, I've never had to work with diagrams and modules before.

Comment: It's easy. I have actually 4 leds connected. Put a resistor connected between the ground and the cathodes. All anodes go to some output pins. My diagram is the same. I happen to have an Arduino nano, currently, but it's the same as an Arduino uno. RX from the module goes to TX on Arduino and vice versa. The + of the pole... someone say it can be connected to +5V. I preferred to be cautious and connected it to 3.3V.

Comment: This is just wonderful, now I'm getting this error when trying to upload the code into the arduino board: avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00 I tried unplugging, plugging, checking the port and board and resetting the board and I'm this close to smashing my laptop against a wall.

Comment: oh never mind, I fixed it by removing the bluetooth modulel, uploading the sketch and then connecting the bluetooth module again to the arduino and look at that!!! its working!!! thank you so much man!:D :D :D

Comment: Sorry, I went to sleep. Yes, I also had it. I fixed it disconnecting EVERYTHING from my Arduino (I removed it from the bradboard), resetting and programming it "NUDE" (without anything connected).

Answer (score 1):

if the led is not on at all, probably the unit doesn't receive power.
if the led is blinking, it's not connected ( it will continue blink after you've paired it)
if the led is solid on, it's connected ( to some kind of communication, such as a bluetooth terminal)

so don't worry if you pair it with your android or laptop and the blinking continues.

the easy way to check that it's working is to give it power on the vcc pin and connect rx with tx, now you can send a byte from a laptop or android, and you should immediately receive the same byte.
i've found both Tera Term and Termite 3.1 to work on windows 8
on android i've found "Bluetooth Terminal" by "Juan Sebastian Ochoa Zambrano" to work
but "Bluetooth Terminal" by "Qwerty" doesn't work for me on Android.

On the computer you will choose a com-port, the default baudrate is 9600.
you can check which com-port it's on in the device manager

Don't confuse HC-06 with HC-05, they work in different ways.

if you use the module on a breakout, it probably has a voltage regulator that takes whatever you put on vcc down to 3.3V, it's a good idea to give it 5V on vcc pin in that case, giving it 3.3V on vcc causes strange behaviour in some cases